# Access JIRA API with api key without username and password

Tags: authentication, jira, jira-rest-api

Currently I'm accessing JIRA API in C#.Net application with username and password. But I need to access the JIRA API without entering a username and a password even without hashed username and passwords. Is there any way to create an API key and access JIRA API with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, JIRA supports OAuth for that purpose, see: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication

Unfortunately there's no C# sample code provided, but you should be able to assemble a solution from the other programming languages here:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src

You should use a generic OAuth library anyhow.

Comment: I got the accesstoken and java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar request ACCESS_TOKEN JIRA_REST_URL these command returned value with correct values. How can I achieve this with c#

Comment: I created another question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214485/access-jira-api-with-c-sharp-using-accesstoken

Answer (score 2):

Oauth is great for when you need the actual user to log in and you are in the context of a browser.

However, for server-to-server communication that is not linked to any specific user (e.g. CI) you may want to create a "bot" account on your jira server and authenticate with API tokens. Creation of tokens is described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html

Then you can use [user-email]:[auth-token] as user/password to basic auth. Examples:

Curl

```
curl -u bot@company.com:AAABBBCCC https://[company].atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/DEV-123
```

NodeJS got:

```
const issueContent = await gotService.get(
  'https://[company].atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/DEV-123',
  {
    auth: 'bot@company.com:AAABBBCCC'
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for this is to read the documentation of the JIRA version you are using, since different versions could have different ways to approach Rest APIs.

For me below endpoint worked with Basic auth:

> ```
> curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
> ```