# Access JIRA API with C# using AccessToken

Tags: c#, oauth, jira-rest-api

I have created AccessToken using https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication tutorial and could connected and get the data from jar file. I need to access it with c# app. I tried following code but it wasn't working.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);  
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_Access_Token);  
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string html = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Original question was [Access JIRA API with api key without username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193366/access-jira-api-with-api-key-without-username-and-password)

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There was no any errors.