# Jira REST API server-to-server authentication

Tags: node.js, rest, api, curl, jira

I didn't find any question that describes how to do server-to-server authentication with Jira API so I'm posting this QA-style. This solution assumes jira cloud but probably translates to other setups as well.

If you are building a webapp and want users to authenticate as themselves, you should look at OAuth as discussed here: [Access JIRA API with api key without username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193366/access-jira-api-with-api-key-without-username-and-password/56441080#56441080)

But if you want a "service-account"/"bot" account on your server to interact with Jira API as "itself", here is how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html

First you (or site admin) needs to create the bot account. Then log in to the account and create an API token from here (assumes Jira cloud): https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens?_ga=2.69222547.2064924674.1559628016-830461555.1535725383

Then you can use [user-email]:[auth-token] as user/password for basic auth. Examples:

Curl

```
curl -u bot@company.com:AAABBBCCC https://[company].atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/DEV-123
```

NodeJS got:

```
const issueContent = await gotService.get(
  'https://[company].atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/DEV-123',
  {
    auth: 'bot@company.com:AAABBBCCC'
  }
)
```

Comment: I am stuck for this in more than week. My scenario is, I have 800 users. In Jira, only user can create their own token.I have a login page for my custom app and when verified in my local db, the login user will then have access to its own resource using thier own token pass in headers in every request.What I need for my app to work is create users token manually in Jira  by an admin and save in db,but theres no way an admin account can create token for a user.

Comment: @rai it sounds like the solution discussed here is not applicable for you since you need individual user's access. As mentioned in the question above I believe you need to look at oauth, there's a stackoverflow link there too.